# Visa requirement for travelling to Turkey as Indian citizen

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, turkey, uk-residents

I am actually from India and I am on T2 skilled visa in UK. I am required to travel to Turkey for some medical treatments. Does that require a visa?

if so what kind of visa required. Is there is any visa on arrival for that?

What does it cost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you obtain a Türkiye eEvisa?

**Yes**. The Republic of Türkiye's eVisa [website FAQ](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/) lists the countries whose citizens may apply for an eVisa. India is listed.

Can you obtain a visa upon your arrival in Türkiye?

**No**. [Another FAQ from the same Turkish website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/can-the-citizens-of-all-the-countries-eligible-for-e-visa-obtain-a-visa-on-arrival/) contains the following:

> While the citizens of the countries listed below can obtain an e-Visa, they are not eligible for visa on arrival.

The list of countries again contains India.

Finally, [this other FAQ page](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) responds to the "How much does the eVisa cost?" question:

> e-Visa fee varies according to country of travel document and type of travel document. Please, click “Apply” button on the homepage and select your country of travel document to find out the e-Visa fee that you are required to pay.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really as you pointed on your comments I got the eVisa today..